# Android-Studio Installation Font error in Arch linux

Tags: android, archlinux, android-studio-3.0

Font Error in Android-Studio:

[image: Font Error in Android-Studio]

I faced the problem while installing Android-Studio-3.0 in Arch Linux distro,
help me solve the issue. I installed using `yaourt` package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fonts used by Android studio are indeed missing.
Here are all the fonts I install on every fresh archlinux install to never think about it anymore:

```
pacman -S xorg-fonts-type1 ttf-dejavu artwiz-fonts font-bh-ttf \
      font-bitstream-speedo gsfonts sdl_ttf ttf-bitstream-vera \
      ttf-cheapskate ttf-liberation \
      ttf-freefont ttf-arphic-uming ttf-baekmuk
```

Comment: yah actually I installed the 'ttf-google-fonts' package available in AUR.It solved ny issue.